# Isn't "any, some, or all" redundant? Why not write just "any"?

Tags: redundancy

Please see the title of this post. In the following quotations, what changes — if anything — if you replace "**any, some[,] or all**" with just "`any`"? Don't these authors need just "`any`"?

I deliberately picked books written by linguists and philosophers, because their professions requires command of language, gift of gab, and eloquence — not verbosity or wordiness! I also quote books from computer science and math, because math requires logic and precision.

## Linguistics and philosophy

#### 1. Chutima Boonthum-Denecke, *Cross-disciplinary Advances in Applied Natural Language Processing* (2012), [Page xviii](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cross_Disciplinary_Advances_in_Applied_N/6aom9gQuWR8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Any,+some,+or+all%22+linguistics&pg=PR18&printsec=frontcover).

> The term *paraphrase* refers to ITS users' attempt to restate a given *target sentence* in their own
> words such that a produced sentence, or *user response*, has the same meaning as the target sentence. The
> challenge posed for researchers is to describe and assess their own approach (computational or statisti-
> cal) to evaluating, characterizing, and/or categorizing, **any, some, or all** of the paraphrase dimensions
> in this corpus. In Chapter 7, Amber Chauncey Strain and Lucille Booker discuss Amazon 's Mechanical
> Turk (MTurk) and its role in ANLP research.

#### 2. Malcolm Coulthard, *The Routledge Handbook of Forensic Linguistics* (2010). [Page number not shown](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Routledge_Handbook_of_Forensic_Lingu/j4nFBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Any,+some,+or+all%22+linguistics&pg=PT1060&printsec=frontcover).

> The lawyers with whom I worked instructed me not to analyze the tapes in
> which Amari and Masloum appeared together or separately without El-
> Hindi, so I couldn't judge whether they produced genuinely
> incriminating utterances (but from all appearances, Masloum was
> considerably less likely). If Amawi was indeed guilty, there is a very
> good chance that his guilt contaminated the case against El-Hindi, since
> it is not unusual for all indicted defendants to be found guilty, even if
> only one of them was. When this happens, the problem lies at least
> partially in the legal system's own intelligence gathering, intelligence
> analysis, and trial procedures. So it is not possible to say for sure that the
> government located **any, some, or all** of the right suspects in this case,
> but, based on the undercover recordings, it is clear that El-Hindi
> provided no evidence of being guilty of anything with which he was
> charged. It is highly likely that the prosecution pursued only one
> hypothesis—that of guilt. This would suggest that the prosecutor's
> intelligence analysis was inadequate.

#### 3. Alice Deignan, *Metaphor and Corpus Linguistics* (2005), [p. 51](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Metaphor_and_Corpus_Linguistics/bp3dHiJEUNQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Any,+some,+or+all%22+linguistics&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover).

> The borderline between literal and metaphorical is difficult to pinpoint with certainty however; arguments could be put forward for considering the third citation as either. At the extreme end of the scale from concrete to abstract, *make* takes objects such as *way, difference, journey, effort, attempt* and *sense*, and it becomes less easy to perceive this use as a metaphor-
> ical mapping of the "creation" sense. As is the case for prepositions, there is
> As is the case for prepositions, there is no simple answer to the question as to whether **any, some or all** non-concrete uses of delexical verbs should be considered to be metaphorical. It is a question that needs to be addressed in any research that attempts to identify metaphors consistently.

#### 4. William Lucy, *Philosophy of Private Law* (2007), [p. 72](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Private_Law/6eKUGhCeieoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Any,+some,+or+all%22+law&pg=PT80&printsec=frontcover).

> That conduct must have as
> one of its outcomes a private law wrong, the exact nature of the wrong
> necessary for liability being determined by the relevant substantive
> branches of private law, which also determine whether the defendant
> actually must be aware — or must simply be capable of being aware — of
> ***any, some* or *all*** of the outcomes of their conduct.

## Computer science

#### 5. Alexey L. Lastovetsky, *Parallel Computing on Heterogeneous Networks* (2008), [p. 120](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Parallel_Computing_on_Heterogeneous_Netw/HCWdUXtj-QMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+computer&pg=PA120&printsec=frontcover).

> In addition to the two basic complete operations, MP I provides various
> complete operations that can be used to wait for the completion of **any, some,
> or all** the operations in a list, rather than having to wait for a specific message.
> The remaining point-to-point communications operations are aimed mainly at
> better optimisation of computer resources such as memory and processor
> cycles. MP1_Probe and MP1_1probe operations allow for incoming messages
> to be checked without actually receiving them. The user can then decide how
> to receive them, based on the information returned by the probe. In particu-
> lar, the user may allocate memory for the receive buffer according to the
> length of the probed message.

#### 6.  James A. Whittaker, *Exploratory Software Testing. Tips, Tricks, Tours, and Techniques to Guide Test Design* (2009). [Page number not shown](https://www.google.om/books/edition/Exploratory_Software_Testing/BsB0NpkcdgIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+software&pg=PT71&printsec=frontcover).

> #### State
>
> The fact that **any, some, or all** inputs can be "remembered" (that is,
> stored in internal data structures) means that we can't just get by with
> selecting an input without taking into account all the inputs that came
> before it. If we apply input a, and it changes the state of the
> application under test, then applying input a again cannot be said to be
> the same test. The application's state has changed, and the outcome of
> applying input a could be very different. State impacts whether an
> application fails every bit as much as input does. Apply an input in
> one state and everything is fine; apply that same input in another state
> and all bets are off.

#### 7. Yingxu Wang, *Breakthroughs in Software Science and Computational Intelligence* (2012), [p. 168](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Breakthroughs_in_Software_Science_and_Co/E5GtZXMNoewC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+software&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover).

> **Definition 3:** message. m::= < n, v, l, p, f, αm, ßm, δ> where
>
> - n is the identification of the message
>   including its sender (a role) and the
>   host's address of its sender;
> - v is the receiver of the message ex-
>   pressed by an identification of a role;
> - l is the pattern of a message, specify-
>   ing the types, sequence and number
>   of parameters;
> - p is a complex object taken as the pa-
>   rameters with the message pattern l;
> - f is a flag that expresses **any, some or all**-message;

## Math

#### 8. Yves Nievergelt, *Logic, Mathematics, and Computer Science Modern Foundations with Practical Applications* (2015), [p. 329](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Logic_Mathematics_and_Computer_Science/AInDCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+computer&pg=PA329&printsec=frontcover).

> [image]

#### 9. Chantal D. Larose, *Data Mining and Predictive Analytics* (2015), [p. 246](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Data_Mining_and_Predictive_Analytics/fFy3BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+statistics&pg=PA246&printsec=frontcoverr).

> [image]

#### 10. G Gettinby, *Experimental Design Techniques in Statistical Practice A Practical Software-Based Approach* (2014), [p. 130](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Data_Mining_and_Predictive_Analytics/fFy3BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+statistics&pg=PA246&printsec=frontcoverr).

> [image]

#### 11.  Ranjit Kumar, *Research Methodology A Step-by-Step Guide for Beginners* (2005), [p. 78](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Research_Methodology/x_kp__WmFzoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22any,+some,+or+all%22+statistics&pg=PA78&printsec=frontcover).

> #### Errors in testing a hypothesis
>
> As already mentioned, a hypothesis is an assumption that may prove to be
> either correct or incorrect. It is possible to arrive at an incorrect conclusion
> about a hypothesis for a variety of reasons. Incorrect conclusions about the
> validity of a hypothesis may be drawn if:
> • the study design selected is faulty;
> • the sampling procedure adopted is faulty;
> • the method of data collection is inaccurate;
> • the analysis is wrong;
> • the statistical procedures applied are inappropriate; or
> the conclusions drawn are incorrect.
>
> **Any, some or all** of these aspects of the research process could be
> responsible for the inadvertent introduction of error in your study, making
> conclusions misleading. Hence, in the testing of a hypothesis there is always

Comment: You overestimate the "gift of gab and eloquence" that academics add to their scholarly writing. They might add it to writing directed to a general audience, but the works you have chosen are academic. Furthermore—in my experience as an academic—most scholars cannot write eloquently even when they try to do so. As to the phrase in question, it is commonly used where exactness is required—even at the expense of verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example that is heavily inspired by your third example but simplified in terms of content (the same logic applies to all examples).

> There is no simple answer to the question as to whether any, some or all animals can swim.

**Here the question is not "Are there animals that can swim?" but "How many animals can swim?". And there are 4 interesting cases:**

1. If **no** animal can swim, we have found a rule that no animals can swim.
2. If **one** animal can swim, we have found a rule (or rather an exception) that that single animal can swim.
3. If **some** animals can swim, we have found another question, namely what the swimming animals have in common.
4. If **all** animals can swim we have found a rule that all animals can swim.

Let's also look at the meaning of the words:

> **Any**: One or more
> **Not any**: none

> **Some**: Two or more
> **Not some**: none or all

> **All**:  All
> **Not all:** none or some

If you leave out "all", you have no way of distiguishing between case 3 and 4, since "some" would apply in both cases.

If you leave out "any" you have no way of expressing case 1. If you ask "some or all", you presume that "none" is not an even an option.

Finally, if you leave out "some" you have no way of distiguishing case 2 and 3, since "any" would apply in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, in the contexts you provided, there is no logical difference between "any" and "any, some or all". That's to say, this sentence describes the exact same set of circumstances as the one in your second example:

> So it is not possible to say for sure that the government located **any** of the right suspects in this case...

But the expression "any, some or all" does have meaning: it suggests three categories for assessing completion: none, some and all. Saying, "I don't know if any, some or all are complete", you're saying you don't know which of the three categories of completeness represents the actual case. This is a slightly different statement than saying "We don't know how complete it is".